# Kraken API. Get Closed Orders count is not correct

Tags: kraken.com

I'm trying to get all closed orders for my account. So I use `/0/private/ClosedOrders` endpoint. In the answer I have `count` = `188`, but if I set offset to `150` for the same request I have more `50` orders in response, and then I set offset `200` and have `5` more, so count is less for `17` orders. How to get actual `count` from this endpoint?

Comment: Did you solve your issue ?
I turned into the same situation, but I think for closed orders you can use start/end datetime parameters in the query.
Maybe the count stops at previous day... try to set the dates, specialy the end date to "datetime.Now"...